# 1pt vertical space after/before \includegraphics

Tags: spacing, graphics, vertical-alignment

Where does the approximately 1-point vertical white space between subsequent figure rows come from? You may see it in my MWE only if you zoom in between the rows. I have tried a couple of things to get rid of it, yet only `\vspace*{-1pt}` seems to help. However, I found this quite symptomatic, and I am not even sure `1pt` is the correct length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100bp.jpg}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}
\setlength\floatsep{0pt}
\setlength\textfloatsep{0pt}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.0}
\begin{document}
    Which \textit{vertical} space is this between the graphics?

    \ig\ig\ig
    %\vspace*{-1pt}

    \ig\ig\ig

    It's here as well:

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \ig\ig\ig
        %\vspace*{-1pt}

        \ig\ig\ig
    \end{figure}

    How do I remove it exactly?
\end{document}
```

Note: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811207/insert-images-with-no-vertical-distance-in-la-tex, yet this one did not receive a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Add `\nointerlineskip` between your sets of `\ig\ig\ig`. Possible duplicate: [Vertical space on top and bottom of inserted image not being equal with vfill?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243730/5764)

Comment: Note that you need a paragraph break before `\nointerlineskip` (for example) or you'll get errors.